# What does this causative sentence mean? Phrase using 「やらせてもらう」

Tags: grammar, translation

I found this sentence in a manga that I fine quite difficult to understand.
"君が言ってたことをそのまま俺もやらせてもらうよ"
Does this sentence mean " I let you do the thing that you have said" ?
Also, the structure of this sentence make me really confused, especially 俺も. Why the subject is in the middle of the sentence?

Here the context: A criminal kidnap the police that used to arrest him and bring him to his hideout. Then, he tortured him. Before in could get any worse, the police partner suddenly appeared. He managed to fine out his hideout. The criminal then attacked him but to no avail and the police partner handcuffs him. The criminal then says just bring him to the police station already. The police partner stare at him and say: “I was thinking about that. But before that…". Then he says this sentence. After that he give him a lot of punches.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It means: I will do exactly what you were saying, too.

You could write the same meaning as "君が言ってたことをそのまま俺もやる", and changing it to "やらせてもらう" is normally a pattern to be more polite. For example, you can say 「寄らせてもらう」instead of 「寄る」 and be more polite that way, because you are expressing gratitude to the listener for their permission. It's similar to adding "thank you for your permission" (but this is of course just a way of expression - it doesn't actually mean you got permission).

This added politeness can be made to have a threatening effect. It emphasizes distance and coldheartedness. In this example, it emphasizes the speaker is calm, and will do the harm coldbloodedly.

そのままやらせてもらう is a common pattern used in describing revenge. Usually, something was done or threatened to the speaker, who then retaliates by doing the same act to the initiator coldbloodedly.