# Understanding ずるいわたしもと割り込んでアネットも何度もやらせてもらった

Tags: grammar

> 「隣の家の子だった。父さんとその子のお父さんは同じ大学の研究者で、友達で、あたしもその子とはたくさん遊んだ。その子のお母さんの家系は代々不思議な力があって、お母さんとその子と年の離れたお兄さんは、離れていてもお互いの気持ちが少しだけわかった」
>
> 父は脳科学者で、人と人とがわかりあう時の脳の働きの研究をしていた。
>
> その子の父親は人工知能の研究者で、人と友達になれる人工知能を作ろうとしていた。
>
> だから研究といったって、危ないことは誰にも一つもしなかった。玩具みたいなセンサをつけて別の部屋のもう一人と話をする、ゲームみたいな他愛もない実験で、ずるいわたし**もと**割り込んで**アネットも**何度もやらせてもらった。再現実験の被験者は父の研究室の学生から希望者を募って、単位と母のお茶菓子目当てにほとんど全員が顔をのぞかせていた。

86─エイティシックス─
安里アサト

I was taught that the agent of やらせてもらう should be marked with に. But in this quote も is used. Could you help me understand this phenomenon? I don’t understand why も is used.

By the way, what is this bold もと? Is it 下(もと)?

Comment: What's アネット? It is the name of the speaker?

Comment: @aguijonazo Yes, it's the name of the speaker.

Answer (score 1):

Here ずるいわたしも is what's actually said by アネット, and と is a plain quotative particle without a corresponding verb (言って is omitted). ずるいわたしも is "(It's) unfair (to do the experiment alone)! Me too!". [This article](https://eitopi.com/zurui-eigo) explains how ずるい is used.

Comment: Thank you. Does that sentence mean アネット wants その子の父親 to do experiment to her? But the agent of やらせてもらう should be the first person and その子の父親  isn't first person.

Comment: @chinoalpha No, Annette wanted the father to allow her to do the experiment. Very verbosely, アネットも\[その子の父親に\]\[実験を\]やらせてもらった = "Annette also had \[その子's father\] let her do \[the experiment\]". The subject of やらせる is その子の父親, and the subject of もらう is アネット.

Comment: Oh, so the agent (causee) of やらせる is アネット. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you again. But if the agent of やらせる is アネット, why do you say the subject of やらせる is その子の父親? I'm a bit confused.

Comment: @chinoalpha 父親がアネットに実験をやらせた is "Father let Annette do the experiment", okay? And this action is what annette "received" as a favor. See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/84047/5010), too.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the sample sentence in your link. But that sentence is a bit different from mine. In the sample sentence in that link, the agent is marked with に (私に食べさせてもらった) while in mine it is marked with も.

Comment: @chinoalpha If you understand アネットは彼に実験をやらせてもらった  ("Annette had him let her do the experiment"), you can get the original sentence by 1) removing 彼に (= その子の父親に, it can be inferred), 2) removing 実験を (it can be inferred) and 3) replacing は to も ("also").

Answer (score 1):

The first も is inside a quote. It should be read this way.

> 「ずるいわたし**も**（する）」と（言いながら）割り込んで

わたし is the agent of する. If it weren't for も, が would have been used.

You could insert に, but that would be interpreted this way.

> 「ずるいわたし**にも**（させて）」と（言いながら）割り込んで

わたし is still the agent of する, but since the verb is used in the causative, it is now marked with に.

The second も may be a bit harder to understand, because of もらう. I suspect you are expecting that part to be parsed like this.

> ?［アネット（= わたし）**に**やらせて］もらった

While this might sometimes occur in casual conversation, it is not quite correct grammatically. The correct structure should be like this.

> アネット（= わたし）**が**［やらせてもらった］

アネット is still the agent of やる. However, she, as the speaker, is also the subject of the clause that ends with もらう, and therefore, should be marked with が (or は if topicalized). You could say that the order of precedence is such that the particle for アネット is dictated by もらう, rather than the causative before it.

も replaces が (or は), and that’s what is happening in both instances here.